# Extracting certain information from a page's source code?

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to "scrap" certain data from a page's source. An example would be:

```
<TH CLASS="ddtitle" scope="colgroup" ><A HREF="/PROD/bwckschd.p_disp_detail_sched?term_in=201370&amp;crn_in=71492">Printing Industry/Typogaphy - 71492 - INT 101 - 0</A></TH>
```

I need the text, "Printing Industry/Typography - 71492 - INT 101 - 0"

What are my options? (copy/paste wont do it because the page house over 40 of these items. I also intend to use this technique for other information.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using XPath?

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/